# Add xaml to top of Listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a listbox which is filled up with items taken from a data contract. I want to add a bit of xaml to the top of the listbox which takes data from another data contract. How do i go about doing this?

```
<phone:PivotItem>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="StatusCommentsList"
                Background="Transparent"
                ItemsSource="{Binding StatusComments}"
                u:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding FetchMoreStatusCommentsDataCommand}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">

                <!-- THIS DOESNT WORK-->          

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Grid Height="auto">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="67" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="389"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent">
                            <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Notification.context.data.created_by.image.thumbnail_link}" Width="62" Height="62"></Image>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Height="auto" Grid.Column="1" Width="389" MaxWidth="389" Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Notification.context.data.created_by.name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" Width="389" MaxWidth="389" />
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Notification.context.data.created_on}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" Width="389" MaxWidth="389" />
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Notification.context.data.rich_value}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" Width="389" MaxWidth="389" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ListBoxItem>

                <!-- /THIS DOESNT WORK -->

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource JamesTransparentButton}" Padding="-5,0,-5,-5" Margin="-7,-12,-7,-7" Height="auto" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" UseLayoutRounding="True" FontSize="0.01">
                                <Grid Height="auto">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="67" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="389"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent">
                                        <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding created_by.image.thumbnail_link}" Width="62" Height="62"></Image>
                                        </Border>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Height="auto" Grid.Column="1" Width="389" MaxWidth="389" Orientation="Vertical" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding created_by.name}" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding created_on}" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" />
                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding value}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" Width="389" MaxWidth="389" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

I tried just adding a new item to the listbox but the data contract would mean i have to instantiate all the sub levels of objects and it would suckkk as they are different domains.

Keep in mind that i want the entire screen to scroll in union... so that it looks like one big long list, regardless of the first being like a default value.

Comment: Have you looked into the `DataTemplateSelector`? That would allow you to use a different template for the first item.

Comment: Hi, you just add layout like Border or Grid inside the StackPanel before the ListBox, so that the layout you added will be in top of your listbox. hope this will work, let me know the response.Thank you.

Comment: It seems to separate the scroll bar if I remove the scrollviewer... and if I leave it there, it locks off the view so there is no scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Put the first item outside the ListBox and disable ScrollViewer for the ListBox so the whole thing will scroll together. Here's an example where the item is a simple TextBlock. You can change it to suit your requirement.

```
<ScrollViewer>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="Item 1"/>
                <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding item}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```